# Windows Storage Error with Windows Application Packaging Project

Tags: c#, uwp, packaging

I have Blank UWP project packed to Windows Application Packaging Project.

Both projects have:

- Target version **Windows 10, version 1903 (10.0; Build 18362)**
- Min version **Windows 10, version 1809 (10.0; Build 17763)**

[image]

I wrote a simple code in **App.xaml.cs** to create setting value

```
using Windows.Storage;
...
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationDataContainer Sett = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    if (Sett.Values["test"] == null)
        {
            Sett.Values["test"] = true;
        }
    // Sett.Values["test"] = true; // Also causes an error
    ...
}
```

When i run TestPkg (x86 debug) i got this message in debug console

```
onecoreuap\base\appmodel\statemanager\winrt\lib\windows.storage.applicationdatafactory.server.cpp(235)\Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.dll!7B6D1391: (caller: 05769996) ReturnHr(1) tid(546c) 8000000B The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range
Msg:[User XXX]
```

Value saved correctly i can read it without problem.
The error only occurs if you pack UWP to Windows Application Packaging Project.

I also tried this with windows.fullTrustProcess (UWP + WPF) on both In both cases, the behavior is similar.

How can i fix this?
Source: https://github.com/steam3d/Windows.Storage.Error

Comment: I have make test sample for testing above code, but I could not reproduce this issue, could you mind share a mini demo for us?

Comment: Here:
https://github.com/steam3d/Windows.Storage.Error

Comment: I have tested your code sample, and it throw exception,  I tried remove applications reference and re-add the package. it works as expect.

Comment: I tried re-add the Windows Application Packaging Project, but I always get this error

Comment: Could you try to clean the solution and delete bin and obj folder?

Comment: I tried clear and delete file and create new project. Always got this error.

Comment: May I share my code sample for you ?

Comment: Yes. It will help. Because I think maybe I have trouble with windows or visual studio

Comment: Here is [demo](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/TestPackage), please check this.

Comment: I tested your solution it did not help. I still get this message. I  also tested it on virtual machine it works without errors.
Also i reinstall vs and check windows on erros. Nothing change.
I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: It may visual studio error. please try to repair it or use other version VS2017 or VS 2019

Answer (score 0):

I also see this error. I’m using VS 2019.
Here are some more data points about the problem. Maybe they will provide a clue.

1. I kept commenting out my app initialization code and eventually found that the one statement
   var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
   would generate the error “The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range”
2. After my app is initialized, I use the statement above before writing to the localSettings. In that case, I get a different error “There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.”
3. It seems to be real time related. In one use case of my app, I issue the statement above every 5 seconds. In that case, I get the error “There are no more endpoints...” at total seconds of 5, 15, 25, etc. but not at total seconds of 10, 20, 30, etc.
   If I put a breakpoint at the statement, and slow things down, then I get the error every time as in 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, etc.

Comment: I also notice this. I am worried. Will my clients experience problems if I create an application with this warning.

Comment: Good news, sort of. I moved my development environment to a newer machine, and the messages went away - both the "outside valid range" and the "no more endpoints" messages. The old machine was about 6 years old and had been upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Maybe something bad was still lingering from Windows 7.

Comment: But it is not good solution. If you get again this error you must reinstall windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error using WinUI 3 Preview 3 with a desktop app packaged in MSIX.

In my case the exception occurred some time during launch. I do have code in there that accesses Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.

The exception I see in my debugger is copied below with a source code line.

onecoreuap\base\appmodel\statemanager\winrt\lib\windows.storage.applicationdatafactory.server.cpp(235)\Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.dll!16891391: (caller: 0E7F9FB1) ReturnHr(1) tid(33bc) 8000000B The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range
Msg:[User S-1-5-21-3122765350-3099923779-1351685958-1002]
Exception thrown at 0x7679A892 (KernelBase.dll) in Q5U.exe: 0x40080202: WinRT transform error (parameters: 0x8000000B, 0x80070490, 0x00000014, 0x005BE3F4).
OnLaunched (Kind=Launch)

Answer (score -4):

Check the bellow code may solved

```js
ApplicationDataContainer Sett = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
var value = Sett.Values["#Test"];
 
if (value == null)
{
   Sett.Values["#Test"] = 5;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. But What does '#" mean?

Comment: The snippet throws (at least for me) an exception when executed.